# How to Split a string in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, string, split

```
AERP|01,KSE;04,NCEL;05,GSE;|<END>
```

this is my string now i want to split it in two arrays like

array1 = 01,04,05. 
array2 = KSE,NCEL,GSE

and ignore `"AERP|" & "|<END>".`

Note: I am working in objective c.

Comment: what did you try that doesn't work, and you need help with? Did you look at documentation for the NSString class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `|`, `;`, `,` are separators of decreasing significance, I would first remove the beginning and the end, then separate into number/mnemonic pairs, then separate the pairs.  It would go something like this:

```
NSString* input = @"AERP|01,KSE;04,NCEL;05,GSE;|<END>";
NSArray* splits = [input componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];
// In real life, check that splits has three elements

NSString* body = [splits objectAtIndex: 1];
splits = [body componentsSeparatedByString: @";"];

NSMutableArray* numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* mnemonics = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString* item in splits)
{
    NSArray* parts = [item componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
    if ([parts count] == 2)
    {
        [numbers addObject: [parts objectAtIndex: 0]]; // Could convert the part to a number here 
                                                       // with NSDecimalNumber numberWithString: or alternative
        [mnemonics addObject: [parts objectAtIndex: 1]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `NSString` `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)separator
```

To construct your own `NSCharacterSet` use `NSMutableCharacterSet`

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *_alnum = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString@"|"];
```

Comment: Or use `-componentsSeparatedByString:`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *stringToParse = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, [string length] - 7)];
/* stringToParse = @"01,KSE;04,NCEL;05,GSE" */
NSArray *keyValuePairs = [stringToParse componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
NSMutableArray *indices = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *labels = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *keyValueString in keyValuePairs) {
    NSArray *keyValuePairing = [keyValueString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; 
    [indices addObject:[keyValuePairing objectAtIndex:0]];
    [labels addObject:[keyValuePairing objectAtIndex:1]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *astring=  @"AERP|01,KSE;04,NCEL;05,GSE;|<END>";
    NSArray *aq=[astring componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    NSString *sw=[aq objectAtIndex:1];
    NSArray *aq2=[sw componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSArray *aq3=[[aq2 objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    NSArray *aq4=[[aq2 objectAtIndex:2] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    NSMutableArray *a1,*a2;
    a1=[NSMutableArray array];
    a2=[NSMutableArray array];
    [a1 addObject:[aq2 objectAtIndex:0]];
    [a1 addObject:[aq3 objectAtIndex:1]];
    [a1 addObject:[aq4 objectAtIndex:1]];
    [a2 addObject:[aq3 objectAtIndex:0]];
    [a2 addObject:[aq4 objectAtIndex:0]];
    [a2 addObject:[aq2 objectAtIndex:3]];
```

modify the names of the array as I have done it in hurry.